# After Publish in Vue js app , i can open the component (.vue) from browser and see all files and app structure , how can i hide those files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, minify

for more information :

The dist files are chunked, also the js,

I want a way to minify the files and no one can open the files (.vue)

Note: I meant files not the element of HTML, I mean vue component files (.vue)

"vue": "^3.2.37",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vue.config.js set:

```
productionSourceMap: false
```